# Dynamically Change database connection for web route laravel

Tags: laravel, database, dynamic, connection

I want to change the database connection dynamically. I have created middleware for changing database connections. it works on API routes. But it does not work on the web routes.

below middleware code:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $cookie_name = 'x-connection-object';
        if(!empty($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
            $connection = trim($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]);
            $db = strlen($connection) ? $connection : 'test213';
            \Config::set('database.default', 'mysql');
            $user = User::where('code', 'like', $db)->first();
            if($school) {
                \Config::set('database.default', $user->connection_name);
            } else {
                $error['institute_code'][]='Please Check Code';
                return response()->json(['errors'=>$error],422);
            }
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

I checked Database Name while running it shows the old database name it does not show the new database name.

Answer (score 1):

use below code in Middleware

```
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::setDefaultConnection('connection1');
```

and for another connection

```
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::setDefaultConnection('connection2');
```